# Layout on top of GlSurfaceView disappears and appears on its own

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have a GLSurfaceView that is rendering an image as a texture. I have attached a GestureDetector to the GLSurfaceView. When the user taps the screen i want to display a linear layout on top of the GLSurfaceView.

Currently when the user taps the GLSurfaceView the linearlayout displays but then disappears on its own in about 2-3 seconds. Every now and then it will flash on the screen for a split second. All this without any interactions from the user.

Any insights to what is happening? Here is what i have tried and some useful info.

1. My GLSurfaceView is set to Render_When_Dirty mode and i have ensured that after the user taps there are no calls to the onDrawFrame method. I know this by logging a statement in the method.
2. I have also verified that the setVisibility(boolean) method of the linearlayout is not being maliciously called.

Here is some code of how the GLSurfaceView is being created.

```
glSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(context) {
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.surfaceDestroyed(holder);
        Logger.w("Surface Destroyed");

        if (sprite != null) {
            // readerBitmap =sprite.bitmap;
            time = sprite.time;
        }
        //glSurfaceView.setBackgroundColor(color.black);

        if (myHandler != null) {
            myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(9);
        }

    }
};

gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureDetector()); 
glSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

// set our renderer to be the main renderer with
sprite = new GlRenderer(context,Global.PICTURES.get(Global.currentPictureIndex),myHandler, tempTime);
glSurfaceView.setRenderer(sprite);
glSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.customTextView1);
tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

//add to the view
mainLayout.removeView(glSurfaceView);
mainLayout.addView(glSurfaceView, 0);
```

P.S. This is on Android 4.0

Answer (score 0):

When you set the render mode to RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY you need to request or invalidate the GLSurfaceView to tell it to redraw itself. It's usually done with a thread that contains a loop requesting the render. Are you doing that?

Comment out the setRenderMode line and see if you get the desired results since the default continuously draws itself.

Hope that helps.